# Execute binary string of C module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, nuitka

Someone created a C module for python with Nuitka. (The original Python code is not available, the module is already compiled - so it is a machine binary file.) I would like to use the code within another tool, which only excepts Python files. So I would like to include the C code into Python.

To get more specific: So far I have the files `thatmodule.pyi` and a `thatmodule.so`. I can include them into my current Python code simply by running `import thatmodule` inside `mymodule.py`. Now I only want one single Python file `mymodule.py`.

My current idea is to copy the code from `thatmodule.pyi` to the beginning of `mymodule.py` and to convert `thatmodule.so` to a binary string with

```
with open('thatmodule.so', mode='rb') as file:
    fileContent = file.read()

... missing ... how to convert fileContent to b'string'...
```

and put this binary string into `mymodule.py`. And then I have to execute this binary string from within my python module `mymodule.py`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write it out to a file (and presumably the `.pyi` too) and then use python's [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to dynamically import it.

Comment: Can you elaborate with a short code example? Also: I noticed, that `fileContent` is no binary string, but just binary... not sure how to convert.

Comment: Sorry, it'd be too complicated for me to write it out for you, and there's lots of questions and things to watch for (what OS, what python version, where do you want to put it, should it be cached, file permissions, set up $PYTHONPATH, etc.). It's a fairly advanced python exercise.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no binary string, but just binary" -- you can put it into your python code as (for instance) base64-encoded string; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a documentation, which describes functions for `thatmodule.so` , you can use the following:

```
import ctypes
mylib = ctypes.CDLL("thatmodule.so")
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)