# Binary shared library to string and back

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to save my shared library as a string within a Python file. For that build the following pipeline for testing purposes. First I load the shared library into Python, convert it into a string and save it. The string within the text file can be embedded as a string into some python module.

```
import binascii

with open('start/mymodule.so', mode='rb') as file:
    fileContent_binary1 = file.read()

fileContent_string = binascii.b2a_qp(fileContent_binary1).decode('utf-8')

with open('start/mymodule.txt', mode='w') as handle:
    handle.write(fileContent_string)
```

Now I want to get the string, turn it back into binary and a executable module:

```
with open('start/mymodule.txt', mode='r') as file:
    fileContent_string = file.read()

fileContent_binary2 = binascii.a2b_qp(fileContent_string.encode('utf-8'))

with open('end/mymodule.so', mode='wb') as handle:
    handle.write(fileContent_binary2)
```

But when I now try to import the new `mymodule.so`, I get

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

This also happens when I do not save the string, but just directly turn the binary into a string and back and save that as `mymodule.so`. So there is definitely a problem with the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands the binary-to-quoted-printable step can discard or mangle bytes that have the value 0x0D, the ASCII Carriage Return character, because by default `b2a_qp` thinks that its input is text and applies special end-of-line handling to it.  That special handling can cause 0x0D bytes to be dropped and/or 0x0A (Line Feed) bytes to be inserted into the result.

To fix, add an `istext=False` argument to the `binascii.b2a_qp` call.  That is, change this:

```py
fileContent_string = binascii.b2a_qp(fileContent_binary1).decode('utf-8')
```

to this:

```py
fileContent_string = binascii.b2a_qp(fileContent_binary1, istext=False).decode('utf-8')
```

That tells `b2a_qp` that it's encoding a binary and that it must not discard or substitute any bytes.

BTW, is there a reason why you're using quoted-printable as the intermediate text format?  Base64 would have been my choice, mostly because the intermediate file would probably be more compact than q-p.

Comment: Well, I wanted to put the printable string into a Python file, embedding the shared library. The reason is that I want to give all that to pyarmor, which only accepts Python files. In a next step I need to figure out how to call the binary shared library without saving it do file. For that I wrote the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788861/execute-binary-string-of-c-module